# When to use $injector in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-injector

As I'm parsing through AngularJS documentation, I thought I would post this to get some other opinions.

My specific scenario is that I have settings I wish to change on an injectable using the run method of my module.  I have a couple of different ways I can access the injectable and wasn't sure if there was a discernible functional advantage to using one over the other.  Or do they boil down to essentially the same thing.

Say for instance my module is defined as thus:

```
var app = angular.module('MyModule', ['some.Third.Party.Module']);
```

Now consider that there is a factory in the third party module with variable that needs to be set.  This can be accomplished by doing the following:

```
app.run(['some.Third.Party.Module.Factory', function (theFactory) {
    theFactory.someVariable = 'foo';
}]);
```

An alternative method would be:

```
app.run(function ($injector) {
    var theFactory = $injector.get('some.Third.Party.Module.Factory');
    theFactory.someVariable = 'foo';
});
```

Is one method better than the other?  Maybe there is a third option I haven't considered yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually using the three different methods (to my knowledge) Angular provides for injecting dependencies.

Angular can identify a dependency solely through the name of a function parameter. You are doing this here when you inject `$injector`.

```
app.run(function ($injector) { ... });
```

The above is quick and easy for development but you can run into problems when minifying code as variable names can change.

For production, and generally a good practice in development is to use annotations as you already have in your second code example for `some.Third.Party.Module.Factory`.

```
app.run(['$injector', function ($injector) { ... }]);
```

The third way I know of is to use `$injector` directly.
This is useful for unit testing and if perhaps you wanted to conditionally switch up which dependency is injected.
It provides dynamic annotation rather than static.

Answer (score 1):

The former is effectively shorthand for the latter, but keep in mind that referencing `$injector` directly will cause problems if you minify the code since that variable will be renamed.  Your first usage is minifaction-proof.

I would generally stick with the first usage, but you [could also use the `$inject` annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) like so:

```
var MyController = function($scope, greeter) {
    // ...
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'greeter'];
someModule.controller('MyController', MyController);
```

This makes sense if you want to add properties to `MyController`'s prototype and still use it as the controller definition.

I'm really not sure of a scenario where you would need to use the `$injector` directly unless you were doing something very fancy.

Also keep in mind the difference between the `run` and `config` methods.  The latter lets you use [providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe) which allow you to configure services used in the `run` method (and when they are injected).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is two cases when you need to get service/factory/whatever via $injector:

1) you have circular dependency, but **you sure** that everything will be fine.

2)you need to get something from "angular-world" from outside of it.

upd: also case provided by @Explosion Pills looks interesting.